# TRIM aligns dates to the left

Tags: excel, vba, trim

**Problem**

While writing this post, I realized what the issue was and fixed it. However, after spending too much time on this, I still would like to know if this is the best way to go about this.

In a worksheet I'm applying a macro to I have a column where some cells contain text, others contain dates (DD.MM.YYYY). Excel automatically aligns text to the left, dates to the right.

I've run into the problem of sometimes having trailing spaces in this column. So I used a for-loop with `TRIM` to make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces. It worked, but all dates are now aligned to the left, whereas before they were aligned to the right. When I double click into one of those cells and then select another cell, the date snaps back to the right (which is what I want), even though I haven't done anything to the cell.

---

**Fix**

It took me way too long to realize (or read attentively) that `TRIM` is for strings.

1. I noticed before running the macro: Dates are automatically aligned to the right, but in the ribbon, in "Alignment", there's no option for horizontal alignment selected. If I do so manually and align the dates to the right and then run the macro, the dates stay to the right.
2. When checking `VarType` before running the macro, I get `8` for the cells with text and `7` for the cells with dates, as expected. After running the macro, however, I get `8` (meaning string) for both. After double clicking into a cell with date and deselecting it, `VarType` is 7 again. In the Excel ribbon it always says that it's a Date (before and after the macro), so Excel seemingly doesn't show me what VBA tells me.
3. My workaround now is this: Before applying `TRIM`, my macro checks the `VarType` of the cell and if it is `7`, it does nothing since the trailing spaces only have been a problem where users enter text. (Alternatively, I could align the dates right and let `TRIM` run over all cells)

This is fine, but is there a better way to do this? Does using `TRIM` on dates have the potential to screw something up? I'm trying to learn something from this.

---

**Code**

For good measure, my sample code, with the fix included.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws          As Worksheet
    Dim searchRng   As Range
    Dim cell        As Variant
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    With ws
        Set searchRng = .Range("A1:A100")
        For Each cell In searchRng
            If VarType(cell) = 7 Then
                'Date -> Do Nothing
            Else
                cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell.Value)
            End If
            
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365?

Comment: You say _When I double click into one of those cells and then select another cell, the date snaps back to the right_  That's because after the Trim, the cell contains text that only looks like a date.  When you start and complete an edit (even without actually changing anything) Excel helpfully recognizes the string as a date format and converts it to a date.  The correct fix would be to do that conversion yourself in your code `cell.Value = CDate(WorksheetFunction.Trim(cell.Value))`

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I have do some testing, and my result is quite different compared to you, is it because excel version?

I have a data in `A1` by put spacing in front of the date as below:

[image]

By executing the following function, the first typename was `string`, however after remove the spacing it end up typename `date`, I think it is not necessary to check the type on your solution?

```
Sub tt()

Debug.Print TypeName(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value)

Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = Trim(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value)

Debug.Print TypeName(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value)

End Sub
```

[image]

So it mean your code can be simplified on the loop as following and still produce the same result, it doesn't matter it is aligned to right:

```
For Each cell In searchRng
    cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
Next cell
```